# JQuery UI tabs selected background not changing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, selected

I am using JQuery UI tabs like this:

http://kyleschaeffer.com/web-controls/simple-jquery-tabs-template/

The problem I'm having is that I have more than one set of tabs. I have a table with several rows and alternating background color white/orange. I want the selected tab to be the same color as the background so that if the even row is orange I want the selected tab to be orange but if it is white I want the tab to be white.

The css I am using is:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a {
padding: 10px 20px 12px 20px;
background: #fff;
border-bottom-style: none;
  }

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected-orange a {
padding: 10px 20px 12px 20px;
background: #ff9900;
border-bottom-style: none;
}
```

Currently every selected tab is showing up as orange. How can I use JQuery or JavaScript to know when the background is even/odd and change the selected tab color accordingly?

Comment: Could you possibly create a fiddle @ jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Cause the rest of your css is unknown I'm quessing, it may work to make the selected tab transparent:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a {
    padding: 10px 20px 12px 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}
```

OR, I quess you know if the table row is odd/even and sets css-classes to the row, like `<tr class="odd">`, then try:

```
.odd .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a {
background: #yourOddColor;
}

.even .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a {
background: #yourEvenColor;
}
```